# Windows Server 2016 IIS - Application not always running, not starting immediately, and starting twice

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, windows-server-2016

I have a Wep API .NET core application running through IIS on Windows Server 2016.

The app is doing a lot more than just replying to its API as it is monitoring events, etc on other services.

I have 3 problems:

- When I start / restart the app through IIS (or when publishing an update), it doesn't do anything until there is a request coming. Then the app gets started. Is there a way to force the app to run immediately?
- The app does a lot of background processing and I find that sometimes it stops doing anything at all. It has tasks on a timer that do not get executed, etc. If I constantly output work to the logger, this doesn't happen
- When the app starts, it sends quite a few things to the log and during that time, I can see it start twice! It starts to display a page worth of log and then it starts again. But here is what's odd: when the app starts, there is a random 'cute name' selected so we can differentiate instances and during the original and the second startup it is the same name, so it shows that it is the same instance, but the init gets called a second time.

Is there something specific about the way apps run in an IIS container that could explain these behaviors?

---

After doing more search, the recommended option is to run as a service, but it's not a possibility in my case, so I still need to make a .Net Core Kestrel app with IIS as a reverse proxy.

And despite the comment below, I still don't find any good solution short of pinging the site regularly to keep it alive.

Comment: Each of the questions have been discussed a million times, so do your homework to read existing discussions. 1) That's default IIS behavior and about how to change that use Google smartly. 2) Stop doing that in web apps on IIS, and Google should tell you alternatives. 3) It really depends on where you log the information of "start". I am not surprised to see something happens twice if you happen to choose a specific location in the pipeline.

Comment: for 1), there are a million posts related to older versions of ASP about adding stuff in web.config, etc which are not relevant to my case (or my version of ASP I should say). About 2) I did google and didn't find any suitable alternative (since I need a solution that doesn't have any asp dependent code as the code lib is shared with non web stuff) and regarding 3), the logger is literally the first thing initialized in the whole app and it is a singleton

Comment: From what I am seeing this is still not possible as of .Net Core 2.   There are Github issues but I didn't see any solutions just a long debate over why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

On the application pool set "Start Mode" to "AlwaysRunning" and on the website, itself, set "Preload Enabled" to "true". With those two settings, the application starts immediately.

EDIT: You have to have "Application Initialization" module enabled on IIS

Comment: I did that on WS2016 and it starts executing only on the first query

Comment: Ok, I had this issue too but on the different server. "Application Initialization module was missing in IIS configuration. "Try to check if you have "Application initialization" module enabled on IIS

Comment: Any other ideas? Seems like I'm in the same boat as @thomas - once upon the time application is shutting down and does not restart anymore until i access it...

Comment: @Alexander I have added my solution to this problem

Answer (score 0):

You must do those steps:

- Turn on "Application Initialization"

  - Go to "Turn Windows features on or off"
  - Select "World Wide Web Services" > "Application Development Features" > "Application
    Initialization"
  - Press "OK"
- Under Connections in IIS click on "Application Pools"

  - Right-click on the website which was created
  - Change "Start Mode" to "AlwaysRunning"
  - Change ".NET CLR Version" to "v4.0"
  - Change "Idle Time-out (minutes)" to "0"
  - Press "OK"
- Go to IIS hosted site "Advanced Settings" (it is positioned on the right side when clicked on site)

  - Change "Preload enabled" to "true"
  - Press "OK"

Comment: I have all this already set up, still have issues. But i think in my case the reason is that everything is hosted inside Azure VM :) And i need to additionally check the settings for Azure...